# Cannot find parent element in DOM tree containing attribute: [wire:id]

Tags: laravel, livewires

I am laravel developer and developing a real time chat room using liveware , i am trying to open chat when i click to user but unfortunatly i am getting error https://flareapp.io/share/OmVDe437#F47 please help me how can resolved that ? thank u.

I am also getting error in console.

[image]

[image]

**app\Http\Livewire\Messaging.php**

```
public $selectedConservation;

    public function mount(){

        $this->selectedConservation = Conservation::query()
        ->where('sender_id',Auth::user()->id)
        ->orwhere('reciever_id',Auth::user()->id)
        ->first();
    }

    public function viewMessages($conservationsId){

        $this->selectedConservation = 
        Conservation::findorFail($conservationsId);
    }
    public function render()
    {

        $conservation = Conservation::query()
                ->where('sender_id',Auth::user()->id)
                ->orwhere('reciever_id',Auth::user()->id)
                ->get();

    return view('livewire.messaging',[

            'conservation' => $conservation,
        ]);
    }
```

**resources\views\livewire\messaging.blade.php**

```
             @foreach ($conservation as $conservations)
              <a href="#"  wire:click.prevent="viewMessages({{ $conservations->id}} )">
                <div class="user-card rounded bg-dark bg-opacity-10 mb-1">
                  <div class="mx-2">
                    <div class="d-flex pt-3">
                      <img class="rounded-circle" width="48px" height="48px" src="{{Config('wfh.file').$conservations->reciever->avator}}" alt="">
                      <div class="notification-text ms-3 w-100">
                        <span class="username fw-bold">{{$conservations->reciever->full_name}}</span>
                        <span class="float-end small"></span>
                        <p class="mt-1 text-muted">You: </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </a>
              @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation on [Dom Diffing Issues](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#dom-diffing-cures). It looks like you need to add a `wire:key="{{ $conversations->id }}"` attribute into your `a` tag so that Livewire can track changes to the list of conversations.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had a rather complex piece of code that I had to convert into a component to resolve this issue.